# how do you borrow a value during match in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm a new to Rust.

I created a structure to hold system information.

```
pub struct systemConfig {
    pub admin_address: String,
    pub engine_name: Option<String>,
    pub group_name: Option<String>
}
```

I want to pass this structure to the make_msg function to create a json body and send it as a request to another server.

```
fn make_msg(config: systemConfig) -> String{
  let (host_name, cpus) = get_system_info();

  let engine_name = match config.engine_name {
    Some(name) => name,
    None => host_name.clone(),
  };

  let group_name = match config.group_name {
    Some(name) => name,
    None => String::from("")
  };

  let msg = json!({
    "engineName": engine_name,
    "groupName": group_name,
    "hostName": host_name,
  });

  msg.to_string()
}
   

 fn get_system_info() -> (String, usize){
  use sysinfo::{ System, SystemExt };

  // monitoring info
  let mut my_system = System::new_all();
  my_system.refresh_all();

  // hostname
  let hostname = get_hostname(&my_system);

  // logical cpu count
  let cpus = get_logical_cpus(&my_system);

  (hostname, cpus)
}
```

I have two questions.

1. engine_name and group_name are values ​​obtained from process argument. The reason that type is defined as Option is that its value is not required. If the engine name is not entered, the hostname is filled in. And If the group name is not entered, it is sent as ""(empty String).
   I used the match syntax, but is there a more appropriate syntax? (if let Some/None,,
   more concise and intuitive)
2. `None => host_name.clone()`,
   If clone() is not performed here, a borrow issue occurs. I'm looking for advice on whether using clone() is the right way, or if there is a better way.

I add test code

```
//cargo.toml
[dependencies]
    sysinfo = "0.23.12"
    serde_json = { version = "1.0", features = ["arbitrary_precision"] }

use sysinfo::{System, SystemExt};
use serde_json::json;

struct systemConfig {
    pub admin_address: String,
    pub engine_name: Option<String>,
    pub group_name: Option<String>
}

fn main() {
    let config = systemConfig {
        admin_address: String::from("127.0.0.1:8080"),
        engine_name: Some(String::from("hello")),
        group_name: Some(String::from("world"))
    };

    let msg = make_msg(config);
    println!("msg: {}", msg);
}

fn make_msg(config: systemConfig) -> String{
    let host_name = get_system_info();

    let engine_name = match config.engine_name {
        Some(name) => name,
        None => host_name.clone(),
    };

    let group_name = match config.group_name {
        Some(name) => name,
        None => String::from("")
    };

    let msg = json!({
    "engineName": engine_name,
    "groupName": group_name,
    "hostName": host_name,
  });

    msg.to_string()
}

fn get_system_info() -> String {
    use sysinfo::{ System, SystemExt };

    // monitoring info
    let mut my_system = System::new_all();
    my_system.refresh_all();

    // hostname
    let hostname = get_hostname(&my_system);

    hostname
}

pub fn get_hostname(s: &System) -> String {
    s.host_name().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: While I understand your question, it's easier to answer if I can just copy-paste it and play around with it. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You are missing the `get_hostname` and `get_logical_cpus`, and the `cpus` variable is unused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used the match syntax, but is there a more appropriate syntax? (if let Some/None,, more concise and intuitive)

`Option` has a few utilities that you could use.  In the `engine_name` case, [`unwrap_or_else()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_else) is less verbose than your `match`:

```
let engine_name = config.engine_name
    .unwrap_or_else(|| host_name.clone());
```

For `group_name` you can use [`unwrap_or_default()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_default) since the `Default` implementation on `String` returns an empty string:

```
let group_name = config.group_name.unwrap_or_default();
```

Note that both of these options are superior in this case to [`unwrap_or()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) since they do not require building the alternative value unless it's needed.  For example, in the `engine_name` case this won't clone `host_name` unless `config.engine_name` is `None`.

> I'm looking for advice on whether using clone() is the right way, or if there is a better way.

You can make it work using only references like this:

```
let engine_name = match &config.engine_name {
  Some(ref name) => name,
  None => &host_name,
};
```

Or, like above, you can use `unwrap_or()` (combined with [`as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref)):

```
let engine_name = config.engine_name.as_ref().unwrap_or(&host_name);
```

However, the JSON `Value::String` variant requires an owned string, so not cloning here isn't really an optimization -- the `json!` macro will just clone it anyway.

Comment: After contemplating, I think your answer is superior to mine. `unwrap_or_else` is more performant than `unwrap_or`, and `unwrap_or_default` is very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions, two answers:

1. The situation of unwrapping or replacing an `Option` is common enough that it got its own function: `Option::unwrap_or`:

```rust
let engine_name = config.engine_name.unwrap_or(host_name.clone());
let group_name = config.group_name.unwrap_or(String::from(""));
```

2. Clone is the right way. In some situations, `engineName` and `hostName` will contain the same string, so a `.clone()` will be required at some point either way.